# Unable to store data using spark streaming in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs, spark-streaming, rdd

I am trying to store data from kafka to hdfs using spark-streaming in java. This is my piece of code.

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> directKafkaStream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        ssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://.../sampleTest.txt");
            rdd.foreach(record -> {
                System.out.println("Got the record : ");
            });
        });
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
```

These are the sbt library dependencies I am using:

```
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.8.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.0.0",
```

In the consumer strategies, I am subscribing to topic list and kafka configurations. But when I send the data using kafka no file is getting generated in the hdfs. 
Also when I run the jar file, it shows sparkstreamingcontext started but no confirmation message is getting printed after that. 
Am I missing something here or is it an issue of spark-streaming kafka dependency mismatch?

Comment: You must use the same version of spark dependencies.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala you mean to say that spark-streaming and spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 should be of same version?

Comment: Yeah,  ` spark-streaming` and `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` should be same version

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I did that but the issue still persists.

Comment: Can you confirm if your subscribed topic has messages in it?

Comment: @KetanKeshri yeah, I checked the kafka consumer bash file, there I filtered the messages by the topic name and corresponding message is being displayed there.

Comment: Instead of saving it in hdfs, try saving it in local file system. Run it in local mode, not cluster mode.